# Excel VBA time zone adjuster

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have tried several ways and failed to get an Excel VBA Userform ComboBox to work with a macro.
Basically our data loggers have no native way of extracting data and putting it into a report. The logged time is always in UTC in the format of Day/Hour/Minute/Seconds. My Userform extracts the log data, makes adjustments and then outputs to Word as a report.

I have been trying to make a ComboBox that allows the user to select a Time Zone to adjust the UTC time of the data to: ie UTC+9 for Japan etc.

Most of the code works but i cant get it to run the nested ElseIf commands, the code always runs the first If regardless and then completes.
I have tried .Value and .ListIndex to get the value from the ComboBox into a string but it just doesn't want to know.

Any help would be appreciated as I just cant make it calculate time adjustments.
Code example is the segments dealing with Time adjustment extracted from the rest of the VBA Project.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Local_Time As Range
    Dim Time_Correction_Value As String

    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "UTC+0"                  ' List Index Value 0
        .AddItem "UTC+1"                  ' List Index Value 1
        .AddItem "UTC+2"                  ' List Index Value 2
        .AddItem "UTC+3"                  ' List Index Value 3
        .AddItem "UTC+4"                  ' List Index Value 4
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 0
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 4 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 4
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CORRECT_TIME_INDEX()

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace what:="**,", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm"

    For Each Local_Time In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

        If Time_Correction_Value = 0 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 1 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 2 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 3 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 4 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(4, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing the Value: combine the two codes and there shouldn't be an issue.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 0
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 4 Then
        Time_Correction_Value = 4
    Else
    End If

    Columns("A:A").Replace what:="**,", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                           ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "h:mm"

    For Each Local_Time In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

        If Time_Correction_Value = 0 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 1 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 2 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 3 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf Time_Correction_Value = 4 Then
            With Local_Time
                .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(4, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "h:mm"
End Sub
```